# How can I add a element in Linked List ascending order if the list not empty

Tags: java, linked-list

How i can add different elements in ascending order suppose i have 5 different element already exists in my list and i want to add new values in the existing list

```
void add(int e) {
    Node nNode = new Node();
    nNode.element = e;
    nNode.next = null;

    if (head == null) {
        head = nNode;
    } else {
        Node tNode = head;
        while (tNode.next != null && head.element>e) {
            head=nNode;
            nNode.next=tNode;
            tNode = tNode.next;
        }
        tNode.next = nNode;
    }
```

This is a java related problem and i am trying for soo longer but it didnot worked for me.
i have changed the algorithm now but still its problematic it is only sorting three elements on the last of the list its not working properly i want to sort this by ascending order

Comment: Hint: adding an element to a linked list requires creating a new Node. You're not creating any node in the code you posted.

Comment: if a create a not in this part 
if(start==null || start.element>e)
            {
            
            }

Comment: Node tNode;
start=tNode
in the if part

Comment: That's not proper English. Creating a node means invoking a Node constructor somehow: `new Node()`. There's no such instruction in the code you posted.

Comment: I have created a extra class 

public class Node{

    public int element;
    node next;

}

how i can do this without any constructor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't create the new Node() to insert the node.
 Lets try the following code.

```
   void aAsc(int e)
    {
    Node node = new Node();
    node.element = e;
    if(start==null)
        {
        start = node;
        }


    Node p=start;

    while(p.next!=null){
        if(p.next.element>e) {
            node.next = p.next;
            p.next = node;
            break;
        }
            p=p.next;
    }

    }
```

Comment: I don't know if this works or not, but you should probably format the answer

Comment: @CyberneticTwerkGuruOrc brother i am looking for answer i am trying this to sort out of this problem for more than 10 days. I want to solve it without using constructor

Comment: @TayyabGulsherVOhra My comment was actually directed to the poster of this answer (not you).  Don't worry.  We'll help you out